# Python: Making a multiple line user input to text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

How the heck can I do this... I'm New to Python and I'm trying to create a recipe catalog program to store all my recipes...

The 'adding a recipe' part of my code:

```
def add_recipe():
    recipe_name = input ("Recipe name: ");
    print('Please add the directions AND ingredients')
    with open (recipe_name + ".txt", "x") as f:
        f.write(input ());
```

I just need the Multi-line user input...

EDIT: I need it to go into a .txt file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `iter(input, '')` to accept input until a blank line:

```
recipe_name = input ("Recipe name: ");
print('Please add the directions AND ingredients')
with open (recipe_name + ".txt", "x") as f:
    for line in iter(input, ''):
        f.write(line + '\n');
```

Comment: This goes straight to a one lined text file though

Comment: Good catch. Corrected then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines) on [`sys.stdin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin):

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdin.readlines()
first line 
second line
third line
<Ctrl+D>
['first line\n', 'second line\n', 'third line\n']
```

Answer (score 0):

OR using a while loop, and keep appending to list:

```
l=[]
a=input()
while a:
   l.append(a)
   a=input()
print(l)
```

Example output:

```
First line
Second line

['First line', 'Second line']
```

Or for full code:

```
reciept_name=input('Reciept: ')
a=input('Your input: ')
with open(reciept_name+'.txt','w') as f:
   while a:
      f.write(a+'\n')
      a=input('Your input: ')
```

Example Output:

```
Reciept: Bob
Your input: 123
Your input: 456
Your input: abc
Your input:
```